# How can I tell if sketch is really uploaded

Tags: atmega16u2, upload

I am trying to figure out how to tell if my sketch upload was really successful.  My Arduino UNO with AVR ISP example loaded and a Chinese AVR ISP programmer board inserted tells me that my sketch was successful but because the memory used in the ATMega328P is lower than I think it should be I can't tell if my sketch really did upload and dumping the file and doing a Windows FC (file compare) just tells me they are different.  The ATMega328P should only have the bootloader prior to my sketch upload.  Looking at the file with an editor tells me nothing other than there are things loaded in memory.

The operating system is Windows 7 using the Arduino 1.8.7 IDE and an Arduino Uno via usb.

Thank you.

Comment: If the verification is enabled and successfull, it should be just fine.

Comment: I agree with KIIV but if you do need more verification, perhaps print some stuff out and check the serial monitor.

Comment: You know it's uploaded if your sketch is working. Is your sketch working?